# How to measure personality using an internet questionnaire?

Tags: personality

I am a computer science student. I am trying to do my project in **personality judgement** with **multiple questions**.

My idea is to make a **software** that asks **multiple questions** from a user and then as a result tell them what type of personality they have.

But it is quite hard for me to work on personality judgement with questionnaire.

Comment: This sort of thing, at least in toy form, is already quite common, and it doesn't seem like you've done much research before asking here.

Comment: i have done research on this

Comment: Okay then, what did you find?

Comment: but i didn't approach to work done with questioner. most of work is done on face-to-face interviews

Comment: The word in english you want is "questionnaire"; a questioner is a person who asks questions. There are tons of online personality tests out there. There are papers written about their use and accuracy. There are many published written personality tests. These things are not very difficult to find.

Comment: yes i read some of them

Comment: Can you suggest some papers in which  personality tests is with questions ?

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=personality+questionnaire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, your question suggests that you need to do a lot more reading. It sounds like you need an adviser who knows at least the basics about personality measurement. Perhaps you need to collaborate with a personality researcher.

If you simply want to administer a personality test and provide feedback to participants, this is fairly straightforward for a personality researcher.

There are a wide range of personality tools that are in the public domain.
You could look, for example, at some of the measures listed on the IPIP website: https://ipip.ori.org/newMultipleconstructs.htm

If you look up the literature on these measures, you might be able to get some basic norms that could inform feedback. Equally, after you have administered a particular test to participants you could develop local norms used to inform feedback.

You could also take a few online measures that provide feedback to get a few ideas:

- http://hexaco.org/hexaco-online
- https://www.personal.psu.edu/~j5j/IPIP/